# rails - how to map routes to multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called `publication.rb` and a model called `user.rb`.  A user can choose to subscribe to various publications and set preferences to how often and which particular sections to receive email from each different publication.

So, a User can choose to receive weekly emails from Pub A and monthly on Pub B.

My question is, how do I go about setting up the routes for this since this is CRUD for a User AND a Publication?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to store what the user's preference is for their email frequency? I feel like you might want a join model, like UserSubscriptions, which has the keys for the User and the Publication, but then also additional fields for email frequency and any other preferences you want to track. Then, you can just route to the Publication, but the form for the preferences is actually an instance of a UserSubscription.

Comment: Yup, the user preferences are stored in a rich join model.

Answer (score 1):

It's a case for nested routing.

```
resources :publications
resources :users do
    resources :publications do
      // methods for subcription
    end
end
```

Now you can access URLs like for subscription:

```
/users/ID/publications/A/subscribe
/users/ID/publications/B/subscribe
```

But URL's like this to manage:

```
/publications/new
/publications/A/edit
etc...
```

Comment: how would this change if I have a separate preference model in the mix?

Comment: my initial reaction would be to nest preferences within children within user, but I am not sure if that is the "rails way"

Comment: What do you mean for "separate preference model in the mix" ?

Comment: I have a user model, a publication model (child model) and then a Preference model that stores the user preference for each publication.

Comment: So, a user publishes "publications". For each publication he has preferences, is it like this? So a user cannot have preferences for a publication which is not his owen?

Comment: a user can choose to receive notifications on different publications.  Those preferences for how often to receive each publication, etc. are stored in a rich join model called Preference. He can only add preferences if user chooses to follow those publications.

Comment: So, the preferences would go in `/users/ID/preferences` where you could list all subscriptions with their preferences.